# CSS background positioning with sprites

Tags: css, background-position

I'm making a sliding door button through sprites and there's one part that is giving me some trouble. Is there any way to set the anchor point AND the background-url image position: So something like this:

```
background-position: 0 -47px top right;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The dimensions of your "window" need to match the image exactly, otherwise, it will be cut/other images be displayed.

You may not specify where to place the sprite (it kinda beats the purpose).

Answer (score 0):

No. "top" and "right" are just aliases for the values 0 and 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If width and height of Your anchor are constant then You can use sprite and define coordinates (0 -47px in Your example). If anchor can have various size then I think better will be cut that background as separate image and add 'top right' position for background. As people above me said- there is no way to use both- 0 -47px and top right values.